# Google Charts Error "Cannot Read Property 'ad' of undefined"

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using GoogleCharts and it was going swimmingly. Then both charts crashed giving me the error  "Cannot Read Property 'ad' of undefined". I don't know what changed to cause the error. Are my scripts misplaced?

here is a screenshot of the html page[failed rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdndb.png)

The graph won't render, not even on load. page initially has no data and a blank graph would render, then after the user submits a form the graph populates.

Now the Graph fails to render or populate on user submit

Code below

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

<head>
    {%- block head %}
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-166860859-1"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-166860859-1');
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    {%- block metas %}
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {%- endblock metas %}

    {%- block styles %}
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{{bootstrap_find_resource('css/bootstrap.css', cdn='bootstrap')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    {%- endblock styles %}

    {%- endblock head %}
</head>

{% block app_content %}




    <style>

        body {
            background-color: #B0C4DE;
            color: #696969;
            font-family: "Open Sans",apple-system,blinkmacsystemfont,"Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue",arial,sans-serif;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

    .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: Merriweather,serif;
    }

    .row {
        background-color: #F8F8FF;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 15px;
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px lightgrey;
    }

    .classroom:hover {
        box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px lightgrey;
    }

    .big-container {
        background-color: #B0C4DE;
        color: black;
    }


    td {
        border: 1px solid darkgrey;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    color: white;
    }

    .green {
        color: green;
    }

    .red {
        color: red;
    }

    .intro {
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #from_data {
        background-color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 5px solid #005eaa;
    }

    </style>


      <!-- this is a hidden tag to protect against cross-side request forgery-->

    <div class="container">

        <form action="/data" method="post">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    <div class="content big-container border border-secondary" id="row q_container" >

            <div class="test">

            </div>

            <div class="row border border-secondary">
                <div class="intro">
                    <h1>Enter a "From" and "To" location to display Covid-19 infection data</h1>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 location">
                    <h1>Travel From</h1>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="from-search-term" id="from-search-term" size="50">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 location">
                    <h1>Travel To</h1>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="to-search-term" id="to-search-term" size="50">
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div>

                    <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="testFunction()" style="height:50px;width:100%; font-size:25px; color:white; background-color:#005eaa">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row border border-secondary">

                <div class="col-md-6 location">


                    <div class="showlater">
                        <h2>Location: {{ start }}</h2>
                        <br>

                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                // Load the Visualization API and the ColumnChart package.
                                google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

                                // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
                                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                                // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
                                // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
                                // draws it.
                                function drawChart() {

                                    // Create our data table.
                                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                                    data.addColumn('string', 'Day');
                                    data.addColumn('number', 'New confirmed infections');
                                    data.addRows([
                                                    // Instead of plugging in the values manually, or reading them
                                                    // from a Data Source like Google Spreadsheets, feed them in
                                                    // using Jinja, the templating system Flask uses.
                                                    // Each iteration evaluates to something like this:
                                                    // ['Saturday', 28],
                                                     {% for item in google_from %}
                                                     ['{{ item[0] }}', {{ item[1] }}],
                                                     {% endfor %}
                                    ]);
                                    console.log("this is what is in google_from");
                                    console.log({{ google_from }});
                                    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.  All the
                                    // options go into a single {}; some options' values go into a nested
                                    // {}. Some values, such as colors, must be given as strings.  The
                                    // Google Charts API is well-documented.
                                    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
                                                    document.getElementById('chart_div1'));

                                    var options = {
                                        title: "30 Day New Infection Totals",
                                        titleTextStyle: {fontName: 'Merriweather,serif', fontSize:20},
                                        legend: 'none',
                                        vAxis: {title: "Confirmed Infections", scaleType: 'log', ticks:[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000],
                                        baseline: 0,
                                        viewWindow: {min: 0, max: 10000}},
                                        colors: ['#005eaa'],
                                        chartArea:{ width:'75%', height:'75%'},
                                    };

                                    chart.draw(data, options,
                                        {legend: 'none', vAxis: {scaleType: 'log', ticks:[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000], baseline: 0, viewWindow: {min: 0, max: 10000}}, colors: ['#005eaa'], chartArea:{ width:'75%', height:'75%'} });
                                }
                            </script>
                        <br>

                        <div id="content">
                        <div id="chart_div1" style=height:300px></div>
                    </div>

                <div id="from_data" >
                            <p>There have been <strong>{{ weekly_from }}</strong> new confimed Covid-19 cases in [LOCATION HERE] over the last seven days</p>
                            {% if direction_from == ' decrease' %}
                                <p>This is a <strong>{{ change_from }}% <span class="green">{{ direction_from }}</span></strong> from the week before </p> <br>
                            {% else %}
                                <p>This is a <strong>{{ change_from }}% <span class="red">{{ direction_from }}</span></strong> from the week before </p> <br>
                            {% endif %}
                            <p>Daily new infections per 1,000 [LOCATION] residents (seven day average): [STATISTIC] </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 location">
                    <div id="to_data">

                    <div class="showlater">
                        <h2>Location: {{ end }}</h2>
                        <br>



                        <div id="content">
                        <div id="chart_div2" style=height:300px></div>
                    </div>
                        <br>

                            <p>There have been <strong>{{ weekly_to }}</strong> new confimed Covid-19 cases in [LOCATION HERE] over the last seven days</p>
                            {% if direction_to == ' decrease' %}
                                <p>This is a <strong>{{ change_to }}% <span class="green">{{ direction_to }}</span></strong> from the week before </p> <br>
                            {% else %}
                                <p>This is a <strong>{{ change_to }}% <span class="red">{{ direction_to }}</span></strong> from the week before </p> <br>
                            {% endif %}
                            <p>Daily new infections per 1,000 [LOCATION] residents (seven day average): [STATISTIC] </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br><br><br><br>
                </div>
```

Comment: for starters, `jsapi` should no longer be used to load google charts. it is an old version and no longer supported. see [update library loader code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code)...

Comment: Did that resolve the issue?

Comment: This was a recent change. I was also using one of the Google charts (Org Chart) and it died in the middle of the day yesterday.

Comment: @WhiteHat - That link was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @WhiteHat I didn't try it yet. I was experimenting with something I ended up not liking when it happen and reverting back to an earlier version of my project solved the issue. I have several other headaches at the moment but if it breaks again I will switch

Comment: glad to hear, you should definitely switch, but please let me know if I can help...